# Angular 7 rxjs/forkJoin : You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: angular

logic component.js file in below.

```
ngOnInit() {  
   const join= forkJoin( this.getReconciliationData()); //import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/forkJoin';
   const subscribe= join.subscribe(result=>this.setReferenceTableData()); //Getting issue here
  }
  getReconciliationData() {
    this.commonService.getMasterData(MaterDataType.LOCALREFERENCES).subscribe(result=>{
      this.categories=result;
      this.categories.forEach(c => {
        c.children.forEach(subC => {
          this.references.push(...subC.references);
        });
        this.subCategories.push(...c.children);
      });
    });

  }
  setReferenceTableData=function(){
    this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(this.references);
  }
```

While execution time getting an error.

```
***core.js:7187 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at Object.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeTo.js.exports.subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:29)
    at Object.from (from.js:11)
    at _loop_1 (forkJoin.js:42)
    at Observable._subscribe (forkJoin.js:67)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:44)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:30)
    at MedicalfileInternalServiceModelComponent.ngOnInit (medicalfile-internal-service-model.component.ts:69)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:24503)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:35163)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:35102).***
```

. I Think here looking return object from getReconciliationData() function. But in my case not required return statement.
Anyone please help us for this issue. I need to one by one function execution.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getReconciliationData()` method returns nothing and it should return an `Observable` which you want to pass to the `forkJoin()` method. But are you sure you need to use it when you have only one thing to subscribe to?

Comment: Exactly not required. I tried for avoid asynchronous execution to this.getReconciliationData() and this.setReferenceTableData() function one by one execution..

Answer (score 0):

`forkJoin` expects array.

Try like this:

```
const join= forkJoin( [this.getReconciliationData()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below modified code . And i don't think you need forkJoin since you have only one observable

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const subscribe = this.getReconciliationData().subscribe(result => {
      this.categories = result;
      this.categories.forEach(c => {
        c.children.forEach(subC => {
          this.references.push(...subC.references);
        });
        this.subCategories.push(...c.children);
      });
      this.setReferenceTableData();
    }
  };

  getReconciliationData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.commonService.getMasterData(MaterDataType.LOCALREFERENCES);

  }
  setReferenceTableData=function(){
    this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(this.references);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fork join expects something such as **Observable**, not **void**. Move the logic from subscribe from the method to the forkJoin subscribe part.

Also forkJoin accepts either an array or a dictionary (https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin).

```
     ngOnInit() {  
               const join= forkJoin([this.getReconciliationData()]); 
               const subscribe= join.subscribe(result=>{
               // here move the part
                  this.categories=result[0];
                  // ...
                  this.setReferenceTableData();
                });
            }
    
          getReconciliationData() {
            return this.commonService.getMasterData(MaterDataType.LOCALREFERENCES);
            }
```